# Efficiently process data in real time and push in database in C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, file

I solved one of the problems I came across and need help on tuning it further to gain performance.

There will be an apache module that receives request over http protocol and respond in few milliseconds. It processes input parameters and put it into cache layer as JSON record. (Currently text files are used as cache).

Another asynchronous module reads JSON records, cook them and push them into MongoDB. This avoid latency in http response that might get added because of MongoDB performance degradation.

There will be multiple machines (currently 12) under Load Balancer and would expect 100 M requests per day which would be ~10-15 GB in size measured when JSON records are written in text files.

Basically I am searching for better data ingestion solution.

About using ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ in producer consumer architecture,

1. Message queues are in memory queues and they might not be able to consume this much data in memory.
2. Data being consumed in MongoDB is important data and we could not cost loosing it in case message queue goes down / crashes for some reason.

Please suggest.

Comment: are you trying to get 1 server to handle 100 Million Post requests into a database on the same server per day?

Comment: No Keith. There are multiple servers (11) to handle this load. Currently with above solutions, I am able to handle 50-60% load.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in both cases each thread is coupled with its matching thread in the other module (either by a fixed file or offset) - this means that you still get bottlenecked if one of the modules is inherently slower than the other, as the threads of the faster module will become underutilized.

Instead, you can use tasks queue (or similar solutions to the multiple producers - multiple consumers problem), and let each thread choose from any available tasks once it becomes free. This will allow you greater freedom in balancing the number of threads in each module. If the front end http module for e.g. is 2x faster than the backend processing, you can spawn 2x more backend threads.

The "price" is that you'll need to maintain the shared queue safely (locking etc..) and make sure it's done efficiently and with no deadlocks.

Comment: I re-framed my question after your post.
I am using MongoDB and consumer performance is totally dependent on MongoDB which may result in larger in-memory task queues.

Comment: @user3067435, these queues are just for holding tasks between the stages, if they grow too much it means your thread allocation is not balanced.

Comment: Improper thread allocation is the thing I recently saw and worked on fixing. Hope that will help.
There are chances when one need to perform maintenance over db in which case queues must persist data for long time.
Will surely be trying one of the message queue and will check how they fit into requirements. Thanks you Leeor for your kind response.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ for this kind of thing and use bulk data inserts into your database, or scale out to other servers as needed.

Comment: message queues are in-memory queue and there is possibility of data loss in case queue goes down / crashes. Also input data size might not fit into memory, ~10-15 GB.

Comment: no, not all of them are, zeromq is, its why its the fastest, but the others generally aren't, though depending on configuration some might be cached, but you can get fully disk committed, your trade off is speed

Comment: Thank you Keith. I worked on zeroMQ but definitely not on others. In case consumers went off (maintenance / issue), then these queues must persist data that's the only concern I am having. Will surely try them. 
I am also be trying 'flume' not sure if it will work better than message queues.

Answer (score 0):

You create HTTP receiver threads to receive the data to be recorded, pushing the incoming data to a receive queue in memory. You create a single database writer thread that does nothing else but takes all received data queued in memory (by the receiver threads), converts them to a single database INSERT with multiple rows, sends them in a single transaction, and after the transaction is done, it goes back to the queue for another batch of received data (the queue collected the data while the previous transaction was in progress). Sending multiple INSERT transactions in parallel to a single database table can result in higher throughput only in special cases, that's the reason why a single writer thread is usually a good choice. Batching together multiple INSERTs into a single transaction will make a much better use of the limited I/O capabilities of HDDs.

Comment: there are not only insert but updates, deletes and read s as well. we are using MongoDB where in-updates won't work but we need to read document first, if exist then update else insert. The ways data modeling is dine does not support 'Upsert'.